# How can I compare directories recursive ignoring comments?

Tags: compare, diff, document-versioning

I would like to compare a complete folder with another folder and see all changes between them. But changes that are only comments (with #) should be ignored as well as any whitespace or newline changes.

With `diff -r` I get nearly all files back cause in my case in every fiele there was the version number added in the head.

The best would be a graphical diff-tool like `Kompare`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but I would check out [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) for a nice, graphical tool. It supports comparison of directories (among [other things](http://meldmerge.org/features.html)) and is designed for software projects possibly under version control.

It runs on Linux, Windows and Mac OS.